# Apache FOP: upgrading from 1.1 to 2.1

Tags: upgrade, apache-fop

I am following the [migration guide](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/upgrading.html), but I don't seem to get it right.

In FOP 1.1 I have this working code:

```
public class XsltFactory {
    private static final String FO_CONFIG_FILE = "/path/to/fop-config.xml";

    private static FopFactory fopFactory;

    private static synchronized void initFopFactory(final ServletContext context) throws Exception {
        Configuration cfg = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder().build(XsltFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(FO_CONFIG_FILE));
        fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
        fopFactory.setURIResolver(new ServletContextURIResolver(context));
        fopFactory.setUserConfig(cfg);
    }
}
```

I adapted the above code to stick with FOP 2.1:

```
public class XsltFactory {
    private static final String FO_CONFIG_FILE = "/path/to/fop-config.xml";

    private static FopFactory fopFactory;

    private static synchronized void initFopFactory(final ServletContext context) throws Exception {
        Configuration cfg = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder().build(XsltFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(FO_CONFIG_FILE));

        FopFactoryBuilder fopFactoryBuilder = new FopFactoryBuilder(
            new URI(ServletContextURIResolver.SERVLET_CONTEXT_PROTOCOL),
            new URIResolverAdapter(new ServletContextURIResolver(context))
        );

        fopFactoryBuilder.setConfiguration(cfg);
        fopFactory = fopFactoryBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Fail to create PDF
    at ....web.controller.PrintPdfController.renderPdf(PrintPdfController.java:181)
    [...]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 16: servlet-context:
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2835)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3038)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
    [...]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

The PDF fails to load, since it failed at being created.

EDIT:

After adding `+ "///"` after `SERVLET_CONTEXT_PROTOCOL` the context, I now get:

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: servlet-context
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:592)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1096)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontDetectorFactory$DefaultFontDetector.detect(FontDetectorFactory.java:94)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It looks right from the documentation. Seems like we had configuration changes when we went from 1.0 to 2.1. It could be your URI or resolver. What's a specific example of the URI you are generating?

Comment: The baseUri generated is "servlet-context:///". I am working with a spring application and cannot provide absolute filesystem paths as baseUri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days of investigation, the migration has finally been done successfully. The problem was coming from the URI resolver, and fixing this problem created new problems, which I solved subsequently.

The guide at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/upgrading.html is of relatively limited help.

The core of the problem is the URI resolver. You now have to define a custom resolver, but NOT as in the example provided at:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/servlets.html

```
ResourceResolver resolver = new ResourceResolver() {
 public OutputStream getOutputStream(URI uri) throws IOException {
  URL url = getServletContext().getResource(uri.toASCIIString());
  return url.openConnection().getOutputStream();
 }

 public Resource getResource(URI uri) throws IOException {
  return new Resource(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(uri.toASCIIString()));
 }
};
```

The right way of doing it is:

```
ResourceResolver resolver = new ResourceResolver() {
 public OutputStream getOutputStream(URI uri) throws IOException {
  URL url = context.getResource(uri.getPath());
  return url.openConnection().getOutputStream();
 }
 public Resource getResource(URI uri) throws IOException {
  return new Resource(context.getResourceAsStream(uri.getPath()));
 }
};
```

Instead of `uri.toASCIIString()`, the correct syntax is `uri.getPath()`.

In addition, we had to remove all "servlet-context:" markup in fonts URIs (in fop-config.xml) and images URIs (in any XSL transformation file or template).

Finally, I got an issue with hyphenation: FOP could not find `.hyp` files anymore, because for some reason, the `baseUri` was being used instead of the custom context resolver (I had to dig into FOP's source files to find out). So, I had to modify the `getResource` method of my custom resolver. I know this is a hack, but it works and it is sufficient for me as I already spent three days on this problem):

```
public OutputStream getOutputStream(URI uri) throws IOException {
  URL url = context.getResource(uri.getPath());
  return url.openConnection().getOutputStream();
 }
 public Resource getResource(URI uri) throws IOException {
  InputStream stream = null;
  /*
   * For some reason, in FOP 2.x, the hyphenator does not use the
   * classpath fop-hyph.jar.
   * 
   * This causes trouble as FOP tries to find "none.hyp" in the
   * war directory. Setting
   * <hyphenation-base>/WEB-INF/hyph</hyphenation-base> in the
   * fop-config.xml file does not solve the issue. The only
   * solution I could find is to programmatically detect when a
   * .hyp file is trying to be loaded. When this occurs, I modify
   * the path so that the resolver gets the right resource.
   * 
   * This is a hack, but after spending three days on it, I just
   * went straight to the point and got a workaround.
   */
  if (uri.getPath().endsWith('.hyp')) {
   String relUri = uri.getPath().substring(uri.getPath().indexOf(baseUri.getPath()) + baseUri.getPath().length());
   stream = context.getResourceAsStream(FopManager.HYPH_DIR + relUri);
  } else {
   stream = context.getResourceAsStream(uri.getPath());
  }
  Resource res = new Resource(stream);
  return res;
 }
};
```

Note that I also had to create the `none.hyp` file manually, since it does not exist in the `.hyp` files provided by [OFFO](http://offo.sourceforge.net/). I just copied `en.hyp` and renamed it `none.hyp`. This solved my last problem.

I hope this saves someone a few days of work ;)